# Connect Access 2016 to remote SQL Server - SQL Server Error 17

Tags: sql-server, authentication, database, microsoft-access, partition-table

Good morning,

I am trying to connect to a SQL server from a remote machine, with ACCESS 2016, using the "External data" option. Both are on the same network.

[image: ODBC]

It is important to note that I am connected as a domain verified user.

I create a new connection with : "New" > (Data source) "SQL Server", and when selecting the SQL server, I give the DNS name of my SQL server in DNS format "SERVER\AWORKS", and I choose the credentials of the verified user.

[image: Credentials]

Knowing that the server has this instance with a Northwind database and a related table where we want to connect to.

[image: Database engine]

Once I click on "Next" I get the following error.

[image: SQL Server error 17]

I looked at the Microsoft docs and it turns out that apparently

> Solution: The firewall on the server is blocking incoming connections.
> Check the firewall settings for the server operating system. Start
> code 0".

So I looked at the firewall settings needed to make the connection work from a remote machine with access [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-ver16) and it turns out that the important ports are the following.

> "Ports Used By the Database Engine By default, the typical ports used
> by SQL Server and associated database engine services are: TCP 1433,
> 4022, 135, 1434, UDP 1434."

All are enabled on my SQL Server as shown below. And of course they are enabled at the "domain" level.

[image: Domain firewall rules]

Despite the open ports, authentication still doesn't work.

However I noticed that if I disable the firewall at the domain level as shown here,

[image: Disable Domain firewall completely]

the connection works with "Server\AWORKS" and I can read the data from "Northwind" as well as the associated tables as shown here.

[image: Tables are red]

Tables

[image: Tables are in ACCESS]

So I would assume it's due to the firewall.

But I still don't know what exactly makes the "Domain" firewall block connections

I want to avoid to expose the SQL server's domain firewall to any risk.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You need to confirm which port is used by your SQL server instance. An instance will use a different port than 1433 which would be only for a default instance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451490/how-to-identify-port-number-of-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your Windows Firewall is off for the Domain Profile. Make sure you are using the Domain Profile. Check by using PowerShell command `Get-NetConnectionProfile`, see property `NetworkCategory` and change either your connection profile or your firewall settings if it does not match.
2. Make sure you know on which port your instance is listening. See this [manual](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver16) for details. My personal preference: Set `Listen All: Yes` and just set a TCP Port on `IPAll` (empty TCP Dynamic Ports)
3. Enable your [Server Browser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-browser-service?view=sql-server-ver16) if it isn't. Using a named instance you'd need it if you won't give a port with the connection string.
4. Check if your client can connect to this listener. Use PowerShell command `Test-NetConnection -Computername Server -Port [instance port/browser port]` See first link for infos on port numbers.
5. Check with [SQL Server Profiler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16) for errors by setting `Show all events`, extend `Errors and Warnings` and enable `User Error Message` let it run and try your connection again. Read the red entries and adjust accordingly.

From your question it is not 100% clear which authentication method you are using. At the last step of this list you should be able to see if your method is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

By default, named instances use dynamic ports.

Take a look at the SQL Server Configurator Manager. The named instance will probably use a different TCP port (static/dynamic).

Configure the firewall as shown in section [Ports Used By the Database Engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access) and [Dynamic Ports](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access)